# brief overview of current docker workflow with nginx

Tags: docker

I have currently installed docker 1.9 and I want to create and work on a nginx instance locally on osx and deploy the nginx instance to ubuntu.

All I can find online are conflicting posts from earlier versions of docker.

Can anyone give me a brief overview of how my workflow should be with docker 1.9 to accomplish this?

Comment: `docker run --name some-nginx -v /some/content:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro -d nginx` where `some-nginx` is the name you want to give the container to identity it and `/some/content` contains the stuff you want to deploy on nginx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by having a simple nginx `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN echo "Europe/London" > /etc/timezone
RUN dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata 

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nginx
RUN apt-get install -y supervisor

ADD supervisor.nginx.conf /etc/supervisor.d/nginx.conf
ADD path/to/your/nginx/config /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

EXPOSE 80
CMD /usr/bin/supervisord -n
```

And a simple `supervisor.nginx.conf`:

```
[program:nginx]
command=/usr/sbin/nginx
stdout_events_enabled=true
stderr_events_enabled=true
```

Then building your image:

```
docker build -t nginx .
```

Then running your nginx container:

```
docker run -d -v /path/to/nginx/config:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default -p 80:80 nginx
```

This is assuming that you don't have anything running on port 80 on your host - if you do, you can change `80:80` to something like `8000:80` (in the format hostPort:containerPort.

Using `-v` and mounting your nginx config from your host is useful to do locally as it allows you to make changes to it without having to go into your container / rebuild it every time, but when you deploy to your server you should run a container that uses a config from inside your image so it's completely repeatable on another machine.

Comment: thanks a lot for this.  How do you run a container  that uses a config from inside the image?

Comment: You `ADD` the config file in your `Dockerfile` (`ADD /path/to/config/file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`) - this requires a docker build every time you change your config file.